# Orderby MYSQL Syntax Wrong Data

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a Table with a Column 'Rechnungnr' and 'Date'
Example 2016/204, 2016/202, 2016/100, 2015/12, 2016/231
and i need the last highest number. Here -> 2016/231.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE Where YEAR(Date) = '2016' ORDER BY length(`Rechnungnr`) DESC LIMIT 1
```

But thats not working :(

Greetz, Malte

Comment: those are not mysql dates, so you can't use the mysql date functions on them until you convert them to actual mysql date/datetime values. those are strings. and length tells you how long the string representation of some value is. lenght(999) is exactly the same as length(000) - you cannot use length to test for "highest number", only "longest number"

Comment: ahhh oke, can i replace the "/" and cast to number? Then sort by highest number?

Comment: Just store dates properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of [char_length()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) and the value of rechnungnr to get the max value this way:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
Where YEAR(Date) = 2016 ORDER BY char_length(`Rechnungnr`) DESC, `Rechnungnr` DESC LIMIT 1
```

char_length() will order the results by the number of characters within `Rechnungnr` field, and then within the equally long strings, we order by the value of the field itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using column name date surrounded by backtics

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE Where YEAR(`Date`) = '2016' ORDER BY length(`Rechnungnr`) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With your existing data set (if I understand the schema correctly) you can try something like this to get the day of year, cast it to an int and then sort on it:

```
SELECT *, CAST(RIGHT(LENGTH(`Rechnungnr`) - (INSTR(`Rechnungnr`, '/') + 1)) AS UNSIGNED) AS `DayOfYear` FROM TABLE Where YEAR(Date) = '2016' ORDER BY `DayOfYear` DESC LIMIT 1
```